# TopoJSON choropleth in R/Leaflet?

Tags: r, leaflet, topojson, choropleth, census

Is it possible to style a TopoJSON file from its features for a choropleth using R/leaflet? Tried a few things, and I'm not sure if this is impossible with the `leaflet` package or if I just don't have the syntax right, especially accessing the properties to enter in the `pal()` function. Here's what I have:

```
pal<-colorNumeric(palette ="YlOrRd",domain = USAdata$GINI) #USAdata data frame I merged with the spdf before converting it to shp/topojson

map<-leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles(options=tileOptions(minZoom = 3)) %>% 
  setMaxBounds(-167.276413,5.499550,-52.233040, 83.162102) %>%
  setView(93.85,37.45,zoom =3) %>%
  #addGeoJSON(geojson = jso5)
  addTopoJSON(topojson=jso, fillColor = ~pal("GINI"))
#addPolygons(data=poly)
```

this throws up an error:

```
"Error in UseMethod("doResolveFormula") : 
  no applicable method for 'doResolveFormula' applied to an object of class "NULL""
```

I also tried converting it to an R object the topojson with fromJSON() and adding style elements, but this won't load after I try send it back with toJSON().

Not sure if relevant, but the topojson was created from a shapefile made following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357580/how-to-combine-state-level-shapefiles-from-the-united-states-census-bureau-into):

with cl:

```
topojson -o 'USApuma.json' --shapefile-encoding utf8 --id-property=+GEOID10 -p GINI,+STATEFP10,+GEOID10 -- 'usaetest.shp'
```

then read in with `readLines()`.

Eventually trying to throw this into a shiny app. Here's [some](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/colors.html) examples I've been [following](http://zevross.com/blog/2015/10/14/manipulating-and-mapping-us-census-data-in-r-using-the-acs-tigris-and-leaflet-packages-3/#make-your-map-leaflet).

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use TopoJSON?  If not consider using the **tigris** package (disclosure: I created and maintain the package).  It'll get you access to just about any Census geographic dataset you need, and plays nicely with **leaflet**.  Here's a brief example in line with what you are doing.    For example, you can get all PUMAs in the continental US with the following code:

```
library(readr)
library(tigris)
library(leaflet)

us_states <- unique(fips_codes$state)[1:51]

continental_states <- us_states[!us_states %in% c("AK", "HI")]

pumas_list <- lapply(continental_states, function(x) {
  pumas(state = x, cb = TRUE)
})

us_pumas <- rbind_tigris(pumas_list)
```

I've generated a sample dataset that measures PUMA median household income for this example; the `geo_join` function from the **tigris** package can merge the dataset to the spatial data frame `us_pumas`:

```
puma_income <- read_csv('http://personal.tcu.edu/kylewalker/data/puma_income.csv')

joined_pumas <- geo_join(us_pumas, puma_income, 'GEOID10', 'GEOID')
```

We can then plot with Leaflet:

```
pal <- colorQuantile(palette = 'YlOrRd', domain = joined_pumas$hhincome, n = 7)

leaflet(joined_pumas) %>% 
  addProviderTiles('CartoDB.Positron') %>% 
  addPolygons(weight = 0.5, fillColor = ~pal(hhincome), 
              color = 'lightgrey', fillOpacity = 0.75, 
              smoothFactor = 0.2) %>% 
  addLegend(pal = pal, 
            values = joined_pumas$hhincome)
```

[image: PUMA median household income]

If you are planning to build a Shiny app, I'd recommend saving out the PUMAs you obtain from **tigris** first as a `.rda` file and reading it in with your Shiny script so you don't have to `rbind_tigris` every time.

Comment: The motivation for using TopoJSON is speed. I've implemented it with an SPDF as you do above, but it's very slow.


re: **tigris** 
I like the package, I just happened to have the data and .shp s already on my drive. I use the `geo_join` to merge the spdf & the data, then I convert to TopoJSON with the command line utility. Leaflet draws the Topo just fine, but but I can't seem to color it with the Topo's attributes--passing a ~pal function to `addTopoJSON` 's `fillColor` argument doesn't work. Again, I'm not sure if this a syntax thing or if it's impossible with `addTopoJSON`